# What does this <<Name>> mean in Tkinter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-idle

I was looking inside the `idlelib` module how the Python programmers have implemented IDLE, and at some point I found the following new syntax: `<<cut>>` or `<<copy>>` inside the file `EditorWindow.py`. Specifically, that syntax seems to be used as an event identifier (I think) for the `bind` function:

```
text.bind("<<cut>>", self.cut)
```

What I am not understanding is why there are some many of them, it seems they were create specifically for that class `EditorWindow`:

```
text.bind("<<cut>>", self.cut)
text.bind("<<copy>>", self.copy)
text.bind("<<paste>>", self.paste)
text.bind("<<center-insert>>", self.center_insert_event)
text.bind("<<help>>", self.help_dialog)
text.bind("<<python-docs>>", self.python_docs)
text.bind("<<about-idle>>", self.about_dialog)
text.bind("<<open-config-dialog>>", self.config_dialog)
text.bind("<<open-module>>", self.open_module)
text.bind("<<do-nothing>>", lambda event: "break")
text.bind("<<select-all>>", self.select_all)
text.bind("<<remove-selection>>", self.remove_selection)
text.bind("<<find>>", self.find_event)
text.bind("<<find-again>>", self.find_again_event)
text.bind("<<find-in-files>>", self.find_in_files_event)
text.bind("<<find-selection>>", self.find_selection_event)
text.bind("<<replace>>", self.replace_event)
text.bind("<<goto-line>>", self.goto_line_event)
text.bind("<<smart-backspace>>",self.smart_backspace_event)
text.bind("<<newline-and-indent>>",self.newline_and_indent_event)
text.bind("<<smart-indent>>",self.smart_indent_event)
text.bind("<<indent-region>>",self.indent_region_event)
text.bind("<<dedent-region>>",self.dedent_region_event)
text.bind("<<comment-region>>",self.comment_region_event)
text.bind("<<uncomment-region>>",self.uncomment_region_event)
text.bind("<<tabify-region>>",self.tabify_region_event)
text.bind("<<untabify-region>>",self.untabify_region_event)
text.bind("<<toggle-tabs>>",self.toggle_tabs_event)
text.bind("<<change-indentwidth>>",self.change_indentwidth_event)
text.bind("<Left>", self.move_at_edge_if_selection(0))
text.bind("<Right>", self.move_at_edge_if_selection(1))
text.bind("<<del-word-left>>", self.del_word_left)
text.bind("<<del-word-right>>", self.del_word_right)
text.bind("<<beginning-of-line>>", self.home_callback)
```

It seems we can also define in some way our events with this syntax `<<EVENT_NAME>>`.

I am using Python 3.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual events, indicated with double rather than single brackets, are part of tcl/tk and are, of course, exposed in tkinter.  For instance, a ttk.Notebook can generate a `"<<NotebookTabChangede>>"` event.

Create virtual events with `widget.add_event(virtual, sequence, ...)`, where `virtual` is a double-bracketed name and each `sequence` is a normal single-bracketed physical event name.  Delete such associations with `Widget.event_delete(virtual, sequence, ...)`.  Get info with `w.event_info(virtual=None)`.  Bind virual events with `bind` just like physical events.  (I got this all from [here](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/virtual-events.html).

Virtual events avoid hard-coding physical events to actions.  In Idle, Options -> Idle preferences -> General -> Custom Key Setting is a table of actions and key bindings.  Each action is both a virtual event and the event handler it is bound to.  Those are fixed, but the key-binding to invoke the events are not.  If you change the key bindings, event_delete and event_add are called as appropriate (and a custom set of key bindings is created or changed and saved to ~/.idlerc/config-keys.cfg).

Comment: So, virtual events, from what I understood, are user-defined events to make the user life easier. For example, if we want an event that is represented by a `<Button>` click + a `<Key>`, we could add it to a widget, using, as you said, `widget.add_event('<<Button-Key-Event>>', '<Button-1>', '<Key>')`, right?

Comment: @nbro As Brian Oakey and I both noted, some tk widgets add virtual events themselves.  Aside from that, yes, your example is the one in the 'here' reference I pointed to.

Answer (score 1):

`<<..>>` is not anything Python specific. It is specific to the [Tk widget toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tk_(software)). Events with double chevrons are [virtual events](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/event.htm).

The editor window is a complex widget, and IDLE needs to handle many different events in that widget in order to implement code editing effectively.